# Get path of electron app for React routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, react-router-v4

I am pretty new to React and React Routing so maybe I'm totally on the wrong path here. Happy for any help! So I have an electron App running like this:

```
// Define Options for Window object.
let windowOptions = {
  width: 1200,
  height: 800,
  frame: false,
  devTools: true,
};

// Define empty winobject
let elWin = {};

Electron.createApp()
.then(() => Electron.createWindow(elWin, './index.html', 'file:', windowOptions))
```

I'm loading my App Component into the container (startView) in index.html:

```
//render App
ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
  <App />
  </BrowserRouter>),
  document.getElementById('startView')
);
```

To make it easier I reduced App to a minimal. So what I basically want is an initial starting View which later holds a login screen. When sucessfully logged in, clicking a login button should lead to a new View. This is where Reacts routing comes into play. App looks like this:

```
const LoggedIn= () => (
  <div> New View</div>
);

const Home = (props) => (
  <div>
  <ul>
    <li><Link to="/newView"><button> Login </button></Link></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
);

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/newView" component={LoggedIn}/>
      </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My problem is I can't get the Home component to render because the inital route of my App is obviously different. Removing the 'exact' parameter works, it renders Home but then the routing is not working anymore for the other route (/newView) which makes sense too. Any chance I can get Home to render on the initial path of my Application while the other routes still working?

Comment: There are only two pages right? Home page with a login button and on clicking login it goes to another page.

Comment: In the end I have 3 or 4 Views but the user is basically guided through them. Means Login -> View1 -> View2 etc. Always getting to the next View by clicking a button

Answer (score 4):

I managed to find a workaround. Accessing the current window location when starting the electron app. Works fine!

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const LoggedIn= () => (
   <div> New View</div>
);

const Home = (props) => (
   <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/newView"><button> Login </button></Link></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
);


const renderHomeRoute = () => {
    if (window.location.pathname.includes('index.html')) {
       return true;
    } else return false;
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          {renderHomeRoute() ? <Route path="/" component={Home} /> : ''}
          <Route path="/newView" component={About} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this as last Route to your Router

```
<Route path="/" component={RedirectToHome} />
```

Define this before

```
const RedirectToHome = () => {
  return (<Redirect to="/" />);
}
```

Don't forget to import `Redirect` from `react-router-dom`

Now you will land at "/" instead of the weird path.